# How to migrate MYSQL database with having different fields name?

Tags: mysql, migration

I have two database `old.sql` & `new.sql`.

I have user table named `user` in `new.sql`. and  `users` in `old.sql`.

table structure for `user` from `new.sql`

```
--
-- Table structure for table `user`
--
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `user`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!50503 SET character_set_client = utf8mb4 */;
CREATE TABLE `user` (
  `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `email` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `firstName` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `lastName` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `phoneNumber` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `role` enum('USER','ADMIN') COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'USER',
  `createdOn` timestamp(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6),
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `User_email_key` (`email`),
  UNIQUE KEY `User_phoneNumber_key` (`phoneNumber`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;
```

and `users` from `old.sql`

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `users`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!50503 SET character_set_client = utf8mb4 */;
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `roleId` int NOT NULL,
  `firstName` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `lastName` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `email` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '1',
  `resetPasswordExpires` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `resetPasswordToken` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `createdAt` datetime NOT NULL,
  `updatedAt` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `email` (`email`),
  KEY `roleId` (`roleId`),
  CONSTRAINT `Users_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`roleId`) REFERENCES `roles` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=884 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;
```

now I want to migrate user from old database to new database.
this is only one table, we have many tables to migrate data.

how can I achieve that ?

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT INTO user
    ( ... )          -- new column names
    SELECT ...       -- old col names / NULL / expressions
        FROM users;
```

The first `...` is the list of columns that you can map easily (eg, firstName), not `id` (because it is `AUTO_INCREMENT`; such will get new numbers), etc.

The second `...` would be simple column names (eg, firstName) or expressions like `IF (role = 3, 'USER', 'ADMIN')`.  It would exclude things like `status`.